# Fixed gun emplacement challenge

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

Is there any challenge/title/emblem that you get for kills with a fixed gun emplacement like the ones found on Bakara or Liberation?  In previous games there was, but I've gotten a 5+ killstreak, and it seems like there was no benefit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The MG Master challenge makes a return, in the last set of unlocked challenges. It requires a 5-kill streak with the mounted miniguns. You might not be able to complete the challenge before unlocking it at level 70.

You're lucky to be playing on a console. We PC players only get the machine gun on Bakara to attempt that challenge with... :(

Comment: Ahh... I see now why I didn't get it.  Miserable level issue.  I'm on like my 4th prestige, but I don't really like hanging around at 70+.  I must have been in the lower levels.  Thanks for answering, now at least I know I'm not crazy.